# GAE Python - How to set a cron job to launch a backend task

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, backend

I'm running a daily reporting task on GAE which since recently is using too much memory to finish. Therefore I'd like to set it as a backend task. I've set the backend as following:

```
backends:
- name: reporting
  class: B4_1G
  options: dynamic
  start: reporting.app
```

In reporting.py there are a number of classes which are defined, which call different reports. My cron.yaml currently looks like this:

```
cron:
- description: update report 1
  url: /reports/report1
  schedule: every day 03:00
- description: update report 2
  url: /reports/report2
  schedule: every day 03:30
```

However logically this just calls the job on the frontend instance, through the app.yaml which currently looks like this:

```
application: appname
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(robots\.txt)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (robots\.txt)
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /sitemap\.xml
  static_files: sitemap.xml
  upload: sitemap\.xml
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
- url: /reports/.*
  script: reporting.app
  login: admin
```

What would I have to change to call these jobs on a backend instance on a daily basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to do this is by migrating the app to modules. Explained here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

After doing so, you can just add following line in the cron.yaml:

```
target: yourmodule
```

This allows the cron job to run on the instance defined in yourmodule.yaml

Answer (score 3):

Depends if you want a [persistent or dynamic](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/backends#Python_Backends_definitions) backend

For a dynamic one

The plan is:

1. A [cron](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron?hl=nl) fires at specific time.
2. Adds a [task on a queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) that will start the backend
3. The backend starts

Example:

app.yaml:

```
- url: /crons/startgooglepluscrawler/
  script: crons.startgooglepluscrawler.app
  login: admin
```

backends.yaml:

```
backends: 
- name: google-plus-crawler
  class: B2
  start: backends.googlepluscrawler.app
  options: dynamic, failfast
  instances: 1
```

crons.yaml:

```
cron:
- description: get daily google plus user followers and followings
  url: /crons/startgooglepluscrawler/
  schedule: every day 09:00
```

queue.yaml:

```
total_storage_limit: 10M
queue:
- name: google-plus-daily-crawling
  rate: 1/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 0
    task_age_limit: 1s
```

On the startgooglepluscrawler.app you need to start the backend with a taskqueue:

```
class StartGooglePlusCrawlerHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        logging.info("Running daily Cron")
        taskqueue.add(queue_name = "google-plus-daily-crawling",
                    url="/_ah/start",
                    method='GET',
                    target=(None if self.is_dev_server() else 'google-plus-crawler'),
                    headers={"X-AppEngine-FailFast":"true"}
                    )
        logging.info("Daily Cron finished")

    def is_dev_server(self):
        return os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Dev')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ("/crons/startgooglepluscrawler/",StartGooglePlusCrawlerHandler)

    ],debug=True)
```

And at the `backends/googlepluscrawler.py` just normally like an app, and a handler to `/_ah/start`:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
            [('/_ah/start', StartHandler)],
            debug=True,
            config=config.config)
```

The above example will fire up the backend instance.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Jimmy, this is very helpful! I'm not sure about the final step though. So now my backend is activated, however how do I make it run the appropriate class from the actual app file?

Comment: @Vincent it is activated by the queue. check here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Python_Push_queues_and_backends

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. On a side note, I was just checking the implementation of modules, which could make this even simpler as far as I currently understand.

Comment: @Vincent sure. I haven't worked with the new modules. I have used the way I proposed since the early times of app engine. It might be that there is a easier way. Maybe someone can answer better or if you manage to get it easier don't forget to post it as an answer.

Comment: Definitely will let you know if I figure it out this week. It looks rather uncomplicated. Still your suggestion has been very helpful. Thanks!